# Adding Local Filenames/References To Array In Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, arrays, enumeration, filenames

how can i cycle thru a local folder to add all (or some) files names and references to that file in an array using actionscript 3.0?

```
var fileArray:Array = new Array();
for (var item:Object in "../myFolder/")
    {
    trace(item.name);
    fileArray.push(item);
    }
```

something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only access the file system using AIR :/, or by having Flex make an HTTP call to a server-side language like ruby/python/php and having it return that information.

Here is an [AIR Directory Listing Example](http://www.danvega.org/blog/index.cfm/2009/1/3/AIR-Directory-Listing-Example) (you'll have to resize the blog's code blocks because of the formatting).

Hope that helps,
Lance